# Type validation when updating a DataRow

Tags: c#, validation, types, datarow, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to validate types when updating a DataRow. I am using the following code:

```
        public static int Write<T>(T data, DataRow row, string FieldName)
        {
        if (null == data)
        {
            row[FieldName] = row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DefaultValue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType is T)
            {
                row[FieldName] = data;
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    row[FieldName] = (row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType)Convert.ChangeType(data, row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType);
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But it's not working. On the if `row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType is T` I compared a GUID column with a GUID and returned false.
The part `(row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType)Convert.ChangeType(data, row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType);` I have a syntax error, the `(row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType)` is not working.

I am open to another type of validation.

Comment: You could try with _row[FieldName] = Convert.ChangeType(data, row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType);_

Comment: GUID of C# and GUID of sql  server are different, so their types can't be compared. GUID of database is generated by the database engine. In fact none of the types between C# and sql can be compared.

Comment: row[FieldName] = Convert.ChangeType(data, row.Table.Columns[FieldName].DataType); do work. Is there any way to compare the types?